# Wrong value in correct json using Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, swift3

I'm facing this strange problem. I have to parse this json and extract "symbol","High","low" and "direction". this is the original json

```
    [{"ID":101,"Symbol":"PKR","Bid":105.7,"Ask":106,"High":105.7,"Low":106,"Change":0,"Direction":"0","CreateDate":"04:38:26","EntityState":2,
"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"v_openmarketrates","EntityContainerName":"tradebizEntities",
"EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":101}],
"IsTemporary":false}},

    {"ID":1,"Symbol":"EUR","Bid":126.696,"Ask":127.327,"High":126.7622,"Low":126.9752,"Change":0.4192,"Direction":"0","CreateDate":"06:37:31","EntityState":2,
"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"v_openmarketrates","EntityContainerName":"tradebizEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":1}],
"IsTemporary":false}}]
```

When i'm parsing this in json, it is fetching all the values correctly except the value of "Direction",like this:

```
    [{
    Ask = 106;
    Bid = "105.7";
    Change = 0;
    CreateDate = "04:38:26";
    Direction = 0;
    EntityKey =     {
        EntityContainerName = tradebizEntities;
        EntityKeyValues =         (
                        {
                Key = ID;
                Value = 101;
            }
        );
        EntitySetName = "v_openmarketrates";
        IsTemporary = 0;
    };
    EntityState = 2;
    High = "105.7";
    ID = 101;
    Low = 106;
    Symbol = PKR;
},

    {
            Ask = "127.265";
            Bid = "126.623";
            Change = "0.3463";
            CreateDate = "06:30:46";
            Direction = 0;
            EntityKey =     {
                EntityContainerName = tradebizEntities;
                EntityKeyValues =         (
                                {
                        Key = ID;
                        Value = 1;
                    }
                );
                EntitySetName = "v_openmarketrates";
                IsTemporary = 0;
            };
            EntityState = 2;
            High = "126.7306";
            ID = 1;
            Low = "126.9752";
            Symbol = EUR;
        }
```

i have no idea how the value inside json is getting changed while parsing even though rest of the values are correct. this is how i'm parsing it.

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])  as? [NSDictionary] {
                print("kerb rates full json = ",jsonResult )
                for field in jsonResult as? [AnyObject] ?? [] {
                    print("fields of kerb rates = \(field)")

                    print("kerb directions \((field["Direction"] as? String)!)")

                    let subfield : AnyObject = (field["EntityKey"] as? AnyObject)!
                    let sub_subfield : AnyObject = (subfield["EntityKeyValues"] as? AnyObject)!
                    print("sub_subfield = \(sub_subfield)")
                    print("subfields = \(subfield)")

                //    for key_Subfield in sub_subfield as? [AnyObject] ?? [] {

                        print("inside loop!")
                        // converting int and bool values
                        let ask = (field["Ask"] as? Int)!
                        let bid = (field["Bid"] as? Int)!
                        let change = (field["Change"] as? Int)!
                        let EntityState = (field["EntityState"] as? Int)!
                        let High = (field["High"] as? Double)!
                        let ID = (field["ID"] as? Int)!
                        let IsTemporary = ""//(subfield["IsTemporary"] as? Bool)!
                        let Low = (field["Low"] as? Double)!
                        let Value = ""//(key_Subfield["Value"] as? Int)!


                        // it is crashing here due to multple dictionaries
                        self.Save_KerbRates(ask: (String(ask)),
                                           bid: (String(bid)),
                                           change: (String(change)),
                                           createDate: (field["CreateDate"] as? String)!,
                                           direction: (field["Direction"] as? String)!,
                                           entityContainerName: "",//(subfield["EntityContainerName"] as? String)!,
                                           entitiySetName:"",// (subfield["EntitySetName"] as? String)!,
                                           entitiyState: (String(EntityState)),
                                           high: (String(High)),
                                           id: (String(ID)),
                                           isTemporary: (String(IsTemporary)),
                                           key:"",// (key_Subfield["Key"] as? String)!,
                                           low: (String(Low)),
                                           symbol: (field["Symbol"] as? String)!,
                                           value: (String(Value)))


                  //  }
                }
```

Update:

After using [[String:Any]]

i'm still getting the wrong value of direction,like this

```
    kerb rates full json =  [["Low": 106, "Direction": 0, "EntityState": 2, "EntityKey": {
    EntityContainerName = tradebizEntities;
    EntityKeyValues =     (
                {
            Key = ID;
            Value = 101;
        }
    );
    EntitySetName = "v_openmarketrates";
    IsTemporary = 0;
}, "ID": 101, "CreateDate": 04:38:26, "Symbol": PKR, "Change": 0, "Ask": 106, "High": 105.7, "Bid": 105.7], ["Low": 126.9752, "Direction": -1, "EntityState": 2, "EntityKey": {
    EntityContainerName = tradebizEntities;
    EntityKeyValues =     (
                {
            Key = ID;
            Value = 1;
        }
    );
    EntitySetName = "v_openmarketrates";
    IsTemporary = 0;
}, "ID": 1, "CreateDate": 07:03:46, "Symbol": EUR, "Change": 0.4403, "Ask": 127.349, "High": 126.7654, "Bid": 126.717],
```

Comment: Horrible code. Don't use `NSDictionary` and don't use  / cast to `AnyObject` in Swift 3. The value for key `Direction` is clearly an `Int`, not a string. And the value for key `bid` is a `Double`, not an `Int` you will lose precision.

Comment: @vadian but the value of direction is in passes as string the json, so you mean the value is getting changed due to parsing it as string?

Comment: Right, it's a string in the JSON, my bad.

Comment: @vadian No prob, So how am i suppose to parse it to get the correct value???

Comment: Use Swift native types and (optional down)cast the objects to the expected type. The root object is `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: @vadian After using [[String:Any]] i'm still getting the wrong values, i have updated the code above please check!!

Comment: @vadian i'm really looking forward for a solution i'm badly stuck!!

Comment: try to use `SwiftyJSON` for parsing the JSON. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: @ViniApp If you don't know **how** to extract the keys and values the tool you are using is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This parses (and prints) all values in the first level of the dictionary and the value for keys `IsTemporary` and `Value` in the second level. All variable names start with a lowercase letter to conform to the naming convention.

The code uses a type alias for convenience.

**Be aware that the code does not use any error handling to check the dictionary keys. If it is not guaranteed that all items contain all keys and values you have to use optional bindings.**

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

do {
    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!) as? [JSONDictionary] {

        for field in jsonResult {

            let ask = field["Ask"] as! Double
            let bid = field["Bid"] as! Double
            let change = field["Change"] as! Double
            let createDate = field["CreateDate"] as! String
            let direction = field["Direction"] as! String
            let entityState = field["EntityState"] as! Int
            let high = field["High"] as! Double
            let id = field["ID"] as! Int
            let low = field["Low"] as! Double
            let symbol = field["Symbol"] as! String

            let entityKey = field["EntityKey"] as! JSONDictionary
            let isTemporary = entityKey["IsTemporary"] as! Bool

            let entityKeyValues = entityKey["EntityKeyValues"] as! [JSONDictionary]
            let value = entityKeyValues[0]["Value"] as! Int
            print(ask, bid, change, createDate, direction, entityState, high, id, low, symbol, isTemporary, value)
        }

    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```